# Add new values to a tag field by pressing enter instead of comma

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs5

I have a tag field and I want my users to be able to add new values to it.  I can achieve this by setting `forceSelection: false`.  The user can type their new entry into the tag field.  When they are done typing the current entry, they can press comma and it will be added.

The problem is that the comma key is not terribly intuitive and more importantly the user cannot add an entry that itself contains a comma.  Is there anyway I can reassign this functionality to the enter key instead?

jsFiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q0psjsx9/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use [`createNewOnEnter`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag-cfg-createNewOnEnter):

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    layout: 'fit',
    padding: 100,
    items: [{
        items: [{
            width: 400,
            xtype: 'tagfield',
            store: ['existing item', 'another existing item'],
            queryMode: 'local',
            forceSelection: false,
            autocomplete: 'off',

            createNewOnEnter: true
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  This by itself only solves half of my problem because there is still the matter of not being able to add new entries that include a comma.  However I found that I can set the delimiter option to something other than ',' (for example, to something like '------------' which I wouldn't expect to ever be entered by the user) and that solves the issue.